# reactJs: set value of one component from another component

Tags: express, reactjs

On click of button in reactjs i want to increment one variable named counter and this increment happens through server side.

Once response comes from express server I want to set returned value in different react component.

How do two different react components communicate in such scenario.

I am using commonJs approach for each components so each component is in different file .

How can I achieve this functionality?

It is like clicking on button adds item to cart for which communication to server is required.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it seems you need a modeln I see three possibilities:

1. Write a model manually inside a specific file/module, update it when the server send the information and bind it to your views with EventEmitter
   https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter
2. You could use backbone so you can have models,collections and native events on update/change...etc http://backbonejs.org/
3. Implement the Flux pattern for reactjs : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/flux-overview.html

Depending on your needs you can choose one of them.